# Disallowing a handler in robots.txt while adding its dynamic URLs to the XML sitemap

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, robots.txt, xml-sitemap, clean-urls

I'm using ASP.NET webforms, and I have a page lets call it `Subjects.aspx`, I don't want crawlers to crawl that page but I want them to crawl the dynamic URLs that are powered by it.  For example `/subjects/{id}/{title}` which routes to `subjects.aspx`.

I used a crawling tool and the page `/Subjects.aspx` was found. Is it okay that i disallow that page in robots.txx like the following:

```
user-agent: *
disallow: /subjects.aspx/
```

while adding the dynamic URLs in sitemap?

Comment: A "route" is a mapping between URLs and the software that powers it.   I've mostly changed your wording from "routes" to "URLs" because you are asking about the URL (which is user and bot visible) and less about the "route" which is an internal thing to the coding of your site.

Comment: You should try to eliminate all links to `subjects.aspx`.   When you run a crawler on your site, you should not have any links to it if possible.  All links should go to the preferred dynamic URLs.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thank you, i dont have any links that points to subjects.aspx though but still it shows in `screaming frog crawling` however, can i disallow it in the robots.txt while adding the dynamic urls (that point to that page) in sitemap ?

Comment: If you don't have any links to it, it wouldn't show up in screaming frog.  You have a link to it somewhere.  Find it and eliminate it.  Screaming frog should be able to tell you where it found that link.

Comment: You can still disallow `/Subjects.aspx` in `robots.txt` and `/subjects/{id}/{title}` will not be blocked (`robots.txt` is prefix matching - and they are different URLs). However, as Stephen as pointed out, if Screaming Frog caller can find it then you must have a link to it somewhere. Screaming Frog only looks at the HTTP _response_ from your server, so there must be something that is _exposed_ in that response.